# Trying to plot contours on Mac using the same script I use on windows on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have an issue with gnuplot on Mac. On windows everything seems fine I can easily draw contours on a "heat map". But on my Mac using the same script I can plot the map but not the contours on top of it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/70j58.jpg here is the two images. One with the contours is on Windows, other one is on Mac.

https://justpaste.it/6ws4h and here is the script.

I tried grid3d but they seem like not nearly accurate as the ones I have plotted on windows.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please clarify, which of the two figures is the windows and which the mac one? Are you using the same gnuplot version on both OS?

Comment: @Eldrad One with the contours is on Windows, other one is on Mac. They were both on Version 5.2 Patch 8 by the time I plotted these, then I decided to upgrade the one on Mac to see if anything is changed now it is on Version 5.4 Patch 3 but the same problem persists.

Comment: Please show the commands used to create the plot. Also please tell us which terminal was used in each case - png? qt? cairo?

Comment: @Ethan https://justpaste.it/6ws4h Here is the full script and I use Qt for both as I use the same script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I will answer my own question.

```
set pm3d map 
set contour surface 
set cntrparam ... 
sp "DATA" u 1:2:3  with pm3d lw 2,"" u 1:2:3 with lines nosurf
```

Solved my problem.!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the difference between your two machines, but I think I can see where the problem arises.   The following lines from your script are inconsistent with producing a plot with both a surface and contours shown:

```
set style data pm3d
set style function pm3d
set pm3d explicit at b
splot DATA with pm3d        # command simplified
```

The issue is that both the default style and the explicit plot command specify `pm3d`, which is a filled-area surface plot.   But contours need to be drawn `with lines` or `with labels`.   You need some combination of defaults and explicit styles that allows you to mix both a surface and lines. I think either of these would do the trick:

```
set pm3d explicit
set style data lines
splot DATA with pm3d
```

or

```
set pm3d implicit
splot DATA with lines
```

Comment: Unfortunately, resolving the inconsistent parts and replace them with the options you have given don't result in a plot with contours. Changing splot DATA with pm3d > with lines, gives the contour surface but then heat map and all else is messed up. Would you like me to send you a data file so you can check ?

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. Instead of sp "hills_cv1_cv3.dat" u 1:2:3  with pm3d lw 2, If I write down sp "hills_cv1_cv3.dat" u 1:2:3  with pm3d lw 2,"" u 1:2:3 with lines nosurf. Then I can now see both contours and map. Thank you for your help.